# Magento get quote id from observer

Tags: php, magento, observers

I'm trying to create order from admin (for telephonic order). In that I've a situation that I need to get quote id from observer. I tried below observer(s)

```
sales_quote_save_after
sales_model_service_quote_submit_success
sales_quote_product_add_after
```

I tried to get id using this,

```
$id = $observer->getQuoteId();
```

And
I tried to print that quote items but I'm getting empty values.

Can any one help me to sort this out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this using below solution,
I used below event

```
sales_quote_item_set_product
```

Actually I tried to set price for configurable product  corresponding associated product's price. And my observer is,

```
$event      = $observer->getEvent();
                $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
                $storeId    = $quote_item->getStoreId();

            if(Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {

                $item       = $observer->getQuoteItem();
                $product    = $observer->getProduct();
                $sku        = $product->getSku();
                $productDetails     =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                            ->setStoreId($storeId)
                            ->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);

                $price      = $productDetails->getPrice();
                $sprice     = $productDetails->getFinalPrice();

                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($sprice);
                $item->setOriginalPrice($price);

                }

                $quote = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getQuote();
```

Answer (score 2):

In the event **sales_quote_product_add_after** the **quote_item** is passed to the Observer.
To get the quote from this Observer and the id:

```
public function yourMethod($observer)
{
   $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
   $quote = $quoteItem->getQuote();
   $id = $quote->getId();
}
```

In the event **sales_model_service_quote_submit_success** you have passed the **order** and the **quote**

```
public function yourMethod($observer)
{
   $order= $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
   $quote= $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
   $id = $quote->getId();
}
```

In the event **sales_quote_save_after** you have passed **quote** since in **app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php**

```
protected $_eventObject = 'quote';
```

Then in your observer you can get it:

```
public function yourMethod($observer)
{
   $quote= $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
   $id = $quote->getId();
}
```